# Angular 2 Firebase - How can I realize SQL behaviour?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I know that it's possible to store one object inside another object. But I don't want to work with this structure.

As example I want to have following structure:

```
{
    courses:
        01: {
            courseName: "English"
        },
        02: {
            courseName: "German"
        }
    teachers:
        01: {
            lastname: "smith",
            forename: "john"
        },
        02: {
            lastname: "schmidt",
            forename: "john"
        }
    coursePerTeacher:
        01: {
            courseID: "01",
            teacherID: "02"
        },
        02: {
            courseID: "02",
            teacherID: "02"
        },
        03: {
            courseID: "01",
            teacherID: "01"
        }
}
```

Each node should be like a table in SQL.

I work with angularfire2 in Angular 2 to a access the firebase database.
The first question is how many services should I create and use? I think I can create a courseService, a teacherService. Is a coursePerTeacherService useful? Or is it better to use only one service with different methods?
My problem is not to create a CRUD in each service. But how can I create a page which shows me that the Teacher John Schmidt is able to teach German and English. John Smith only teaches English.

My Problem is that my current success is that I only can show which is stored in the coursePerTeacher node. But from this I want to sum up by the teacher and show which is behind the referenced id's. In other words the names.

I really don't know how I can code it. What's the part in the component class and what's the part in the service class?

The next thing is what can I do on a behaviour like this structure?

```
{
    categories:
        01: {
            cat_name: "java programming",
            cat_description: "here is everything you need to know about java"
        },
        02: {
            cat_name: "html",
            cat_description: "...."
        }
    topics:
        01: {
            topic_subject: "need help in java",
            topic_date: "08/01/2017",
            topic_cat: "01",
            topic_by: "01"
        },
    replies:
        01: {
            reply_content: "java doesn't work anymore?",
            reply_date: "08/01/2017",
            reply_topic: "01",
            reply_by: "01",
        },
        02: {
            reply_content: "what's your specific question?",
            reply_date: "08/01/2017",
            reply_topic: "01",
            reply_by: "02",
        },
    users:
        01: {
            username: "newbie",
        }
        02: {
            username: "proCoder",
        }
}
```

I curently don't have a real example. I hope it's understandable what I mean and there are no errors in the structure.

How should I work, if the reference is not inside a specific node? How should I work if it's in each object?

I really have trouble with it. A detailed tutorial or a simple example (Component and Service) would be really nice.

I never worked with NoSQL-Databases before.

Sorry for bad English, in my country it's in the middle of the night.

Answer (score 0):

For your Firebase questions coming from a sql background this playlist will help you a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s

Most of the time you can just insert the firebase service in your component and do the logic there. If you need extra services(not Firebase) or don`t want to duplicate your code is probably better to have just a TeacherService and then depends if you want to lazy load your courses you create a CourseService. If in the same screen you show the teachers and the courses you can do all in one service. So to resume it is better to model your service after your views.

if you gonna use firebase in your service you can do something like:
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable()
export class TeacherService{
  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

  getTeachers(): FirebaseListObservable {
    return this.af.database.list('/teachers');
  }

  addTeacher(teacher: string) {
    return this.af.database.list('/teachers').push(teacher);
  }

  deleteTeacher(teacher: any) {
    return this.af.database.list('/teachers').remove(teacher)
  }

getCourses(teacher:any){
    return this.af.database.list('/teachers/'+teacher.key+'/courses') //this depends on how you structure your db
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this video as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BTh9hZ3Hs8&list=PLOa5YIicjJ-WHcyUgtm6XprmgoaC7WRL9&index=5